# How to make https request and encrypt POST parameters?

Tags: ios, api, rest, ios5, https

I have developed a Mobile application that connect to my Web Servie via RESTful API.

Now, I need to protect my API by someone who could sniff it via WireShark. I just need to hide my URL and POSTed parameters in some way...How can i do it?

My risk is that if "someone" get my API's Url and change ?user_id parameter of each request could act as another users, and do bad things...

(I don't use Oauth 2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use HTTPS

The client connects to the server

Client and Server perform the SSL Handshake 
Clients sends encrypted something like

```
POST /resource/ HTTP1.1 

Name=Jonathan+Doe&Age=23&Formula=a+%2B+b+%3D%3D+13%25%21
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to switch to HTTPS. This will encrypt your POST parameters.

Your second step is to fix your protocol to authenticate the user. It will always be possible to reverse engineer your protocol. If the only authentication is a user_id parameter, then you are vulnerable. No amount of obfuscation will protect you. Your protocol must be resilient to connection by unauthorized applications.